# Dynamic ImageButton ImageClickEventHandler not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I have created a button on a web page that when it is clicked will get images from `Server.MapPath(...)` and turns the images into ImageButtons. After clicking on these ImageButtons they should appear in another image enlarged.

The images (as buttons) appear correct on the site and are clickable, however, nothing happens.
Debugging showed that the `imgBtnClick` method is never called.

The problem is that method specified in ImageClickEventHandler is not triggered. *Any suggestion as to why this is happening is much appreciated.*

Please find below my code sample.

**Code executed when the main button is clicked**

```
protected void Logo_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
     Logo.CssClass = "Highlight";      
     Images();
     Panel_Photo.Visible = true;
}
```

**Images method where dynamic image buttons are created for all images at `Server.MapPath(...)`**

```
protected void Images()
{
    foreach (string strFileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/Photos/Stuff")))
    {
        ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(strFileName);
        imgBtn.ImageUrl = "~/images/Photos/Stuff/" + fileInfo.Name;
        imgBtn.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        imgBtn.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
        imgBtn.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
        imgBtn.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imgBtnClick);
        imgBtn.OnClientClick = "return false";
        Panel_Photo.Controls.Add(imgBtn);
    }
}
```

**Final method that should show the image from the clicked image button in another image**

```
void imgBtnClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    LabelPhoto.Text = "test";
    ImageClicked.ImageUrl = ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl;
}
```

The label and 'ImageClicked' are created in the aspx page `<asp:Image ID="ImageClicked" runat="server"></asp:Image>`

`Panel_Photo` and `ImageClicked` are in different divs, next to each other on the web page.

Comment: Did you try doing that on page_load?

Comment: if `Images()` is inside an IsPostBack check. Place it outside.

Comment: @ademg Move what to page_load? This seems to suggest the same, but unclear to me sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762696/c-sharp-imagebutton-click-event-not-fired

Comment: @VDWWD not the case

Comment: @ademg I moved the whole ```foreach``` code block to the Page_Load method, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: imgBtnClick onclick event will not be reached, because of the following code: `imgBtn.OnClientClick = "return false";` - you need to remove this or return true

Comment: @Greg That is not true. I added this line of code to avoid the page from refreshing after an ```imgBtn``` is clicked. Furthermore, when I remove this line and click on an ImageButton, my ```Panel_Photo``` is gone until I click the 'main' button again, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: @Dieter 'OnClientClick' is a JavaScript event that fires before OnClick event. False stops the sever event, True allows the server event. The Panel_Photo is `gone` because the controls were added manually in an on-click event and are not maintained on postback. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150690/asp-net-panel-loses-viewstate-on-postback

Answer (score 0):

Both the comments from @ademg and @Greg helped me find the solution.

I basically had to put the whole `foreach` code block in the Page_Load method AND remove the line `imgBtn.OnClientClick = "return false";`

Whenever an `imgBtn` (image) is clicked, the web page jumps to the top, but that is another issue to look into.

Comment: That will work, a simpler solution will be to bind Directory.GetFiles() to a Repeater that contains images. If you need hide/ show stuff then uses CSS and JavaScript

Comment: The solution for the page jumps is to add ```MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"``` to the aspx code and was found here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/545067/Preventplusaspxpluspageplusjumpingplustoplustheplu